# Is the following sentence a set phrase?

Tags: set-phrases

> 本日はお忙しいところ、ありがとうございます

A book I'm learning from translates this sentence as
'thank you for taking time out of your busy schedule today'

Is the first part a set phrase or is it just an elaborate translation? (As an aside I feel like it would make more literal sense with の rather than は)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree. It's an elaborate translation and it's a good way of putting it. Literally it simply says

```
"Today + (at a) busy time + thank you."
```

I also think it's a set phrase given that it's very common in emails and business correspondence.

Answer (score 1):

本日は is Highlighting today's day.　
Often used scenes,
'Today is the day of marriage'. 
Today' is in a larger sense to thank everyone.
So the speaker says the day, Still as a short and smart way of saying is "本日は".
Meanings are "本日（のeventのために皆様）は".
Nowadays , many idioms are used in the business scene.
Because it looks like a little but overstated.